# AudioRecord failing after 48 hours

Tags: android, buffer-overflow, audiorecord

I am starting a simple audiorecord instance and reading from the buffer (10 times minbufsize) at 44.1kHz, averaging to 441 Hz and this is fine for 48 hours of recording.

Some random time after 48 hours the recoredr stops (rather than crashes) with the message

E/AudioFlinger(  128): TrackBase::getBuffer buffer out of range:
E/AudioFlinger(  128):     start: 0x42242844, end 0x42256044 , mBuffer 0x4224c044 mBufferEnd 0x42256044
E/AudioFlinger(  128):                     server -3072, serverBase 16384, user -4096, userBase -4096
W/AudioFlinger(  128): RecordThread: buffer overflow

I thought the OS might be off checking something and the buffer overflows, but when I put loops inside a smaller buffer to try and make it fail, all I get is the warning

W/AudioFlinger(  128): RecordThread: buffer overflow

and the app carries on as expected.

I can't see what is the problem after 48 hrs and I can't force the problem to repeat in a shorter timescale so I can debug. help!

Comment: It's possible that there's one or more 32-bit counters used internally that are wrapping around without being handled properly.

Comment: Hi Michael.  Thanks -  it certainly looks like this.  2^32= 4.29497e+09 and the program fails after a long counter reaches 4.2949397E7.  Each time this long counter goes up by 1 there is a 100 loop, but no counters are used...

Comment: But I am creating a short [100] each time.  Could this be a memory leak?

Comment: Michael, thanks, you were right.  Audiorecorder must have an internal 32 bit counter.  It's not in my code, but solved by closing and reopening Audiorecorder occasionally.

Answer (score 0):

Great question and comments. I had audioplayer 24h/7d running as a foreground service but stopped working after two days. Mediaplayer did not throw userlevel exceptions, no onError triggered, player.isRunning() returned true. It was adb logcat showed *AudioFlinger TrackBase::getBuffer buffer out of range* which gave me google keywords.

My solution is to run scheduled watchdog 10sec intervals worker task. Task reads player.getCurrentPosition() milliseconds and then

- if curPos duration > 6h AND systime 06:00 in the morning then restart stream. No one is listening for the stream at this time so few seconds glitch does not matter.
- if curPos duration > 40h then restart stream, failsafe in case 06:00 time was skipped
- if curPos==prevPos then watchdogCounter++ else watchdogCounter=0
- if watchdogCounter>3 then restart stalled stream

This simple business logic does the magic. My device is Huawei smartphone Android 2.3.6